# rate limit apache httpd server

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, rate-limiting

I have an apache server that acts as a load balancer to pass off requests to tomcat application servers.  I wish to rate limit the http access by ips, and potentially throttle requests, how can this be done?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/252555/limit-simultaneous-connections-per-ip-with-apache2

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution can be using iproute2 htb. see this for an idea:
http://luxik.cdi.cz/~devik/qos/htb/manual/userg.htm